# Can't use Java 18.0.1.1 and Gradle 7.3.3 to import Gradle project android

Tags: java, android, react-native, gradle

I have installed with version 0.68.2 due to the fact that I got error while installation.

The app installed successfully, but when I opened the project, I got an error:

`Can't use Java 18.0.1.1 and Gradle 7.3.3 to import Gradle project android.`

How to resolve this issue?

I have tried to search. It needs gradle version 7.5 to use java 18, but I don't know how to upgrade or downgrade gradle versions.

Answer (score 0):

Try following steps to change gradle version.

1. Navigate to the root location of the project, then gradle/wrappper
   folder, Find the gradle-wrapper.properties file in above folder.
2. Change the distributionUrl to the required version
   https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-bin.zip